# Scatter Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, scatter

I have a set of data:

```
A = [2/3 -1/3 -1/3 ; -1/3 2/3 -1/3 ; -1/3 -1/3 2/3]
B = [ 0 0 0 ]
C = [ 0 0 1 ]'
D = [ 0 1 0 ]'
p00 =A*B-A*B
p01 =A*B-A*C
p02 = A*B-A*D
```

and so on...

I need to do a scatter plot of `poo`,`po1` and `po2`.

Stated in matlab that my m-file for scatter plotting are `Too many input arguments`.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and where the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are x,y,z coordinate vectors, try:

```
scatter3(p00, p01, p02)
```